# How do I use nested ng-repeat in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to repeat 4 elements in a 2x2 matrix format with top and bottom separate rows. For that I'm using ng-repeat to repeat the top and bottom rows and then another ng-repeat inside to repeat the two elements. I have done it and got the required format. But my problem is that I need to provide different titles for these 4 elements(div). How can I give the titles in an array so that it will be repeated in both rows? Below is my code:

```
<div class="massage-type-section" ng-controller="massageController">
    <div class="select-massage-type" ng-repeat="item in massage">
        <div class="massage-choice" ng-repeat="type in massageType">
            <div class="massage-choice-icon">
                <img src="images/single-icon-deselect.png">
                <img src="images/single-icon.png">
            </div>
            <p class="massage-title">{{type.title}}</p>
            <p class="section-details">One massage practitioner comes to massage one person.</p>
            <div class="type-selected"><img src="images/selected.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function massageController($scope) {
    $scope.massage = [{}, {}];
    $scope.massageType = [
        { title: 'Single' },
        { title: 'Couple' }
    ];
};
```

Comment: Could you provide an illustrative example to make your requirement more clear. I wasn't able to figure out your requirement based on what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary requirement in the inner array is only to display the massage Type titles, your array looks good. Please mark as answer if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is to give different titles in different levels use  $index or  $parent.$index in appropriate way.

To find the index of an item in the collection use $index property
To get the index of the parent element
Use $parent.$index or
Use ng-init="parentIndex = $index"